# Commenting out lines with a specific substring across multiple files in Sublime/Linux

Tags: linux, ide, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have a bunch of files that contain lines that I want to comment out containing a specific string.

In the following example, I'd need to comment out only the lines with substring `Sensor`. I'm using Sublime editor so doing through that would be amazing but if there's a possibility with some linux commands, that would work too.

```c
//fileA.c
printf ("Sensor reading A");  // need to comment out this
// ...

// fileB.C
printf ("Function starts...");
printf ("Sensor A value");   // need to comment out this
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In shell:

```sh
for file in *.c; do # Adjust as needed
    printf '%s\n' 'g/Sensor/s!^!//!' w | ed -s "$file"
done
```

For each file, open it with the standard POSIX file editor `ed`, and add `//` to the beginning of any line containing `Sensor`, then save the file.

Comment: thanks. mind explaining the regex here? also what if you'd want to include more than a single substring? `Sensor` and `sensor`? or even better, search while not taking into account the casing

Comment: also is `*.c` going to search through the files existing in the current directory only or the files existing in subdirectory and so forth? I'm looking for something latter

Comment: `*.c` only matches files in the current directory. Like the comment says, adjust to match what you need. `/[Ss]ensor/` for matching Sensor and sensor.

Comment: any way the search could be recursive to go through sub directories as well?